# excel vba - check if radio button is selected?

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

[image: bt]

I'm trying to check the value of these simple radio button groups but my syntax is off, does anyone know what to change?
Note: they are Excel Option Buttons not ActiveX ones and they are not on a userform.

```
 If Worksheets("Input").Shapes("Option Button 3").Select.Value = xlOn Then
     MsgBox "fir"
 ElseIf Worksheets("Input").Shapes("Option Button 4").Select.Value = xlOn Then
     MsgBox "sec"
 Else
     MsgBox "none" 'in case they were deleted off the sheet
 End If
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub ZX()
    Dim shp3 As Shape
    Dim shp4 As Shape

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp3 = Worksheets("Input").Shapes("Option Button 3")
    Set shp4 = Worksheets("Input").Shapes("Option Button 4")
    On Error Goto 0 
    If shp3 Is Nothing Then
        If shp4 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "none" 'in case they were deleted off the sheet
        ElseIf shp4.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
            MsgBox "sec"
        Else
            MsgBox "Only Button 4 exists and it is off"
        End If
    Else
        If shp3.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
            MsgBox "fir"
        Else
            If shp4 Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Only Button 3 exists and it is off"
            ElseIf shp4.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
                MsgBox "sec"
            Else
                MsgBox "Both exists, both are off"
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. To solve it, I decided to use a toggle button with this macro VBA code to access its value and toggle my display accordingly to it:

```
Call ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").toggleDisplay(CBool(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").ToggleButton1.Value))
```