# How can I find the shape that is selected in group box in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a group box with option buttons in it and I need to find out which one of them is selected in VBA. I have been browsing MSDN for hours now and I can't find a solution.

There has to be a way to find the selected option button. Possibly find the group by name and for-each through each option button?

Comment: do you have any initial code? which way you grouped your Option Buttons?

Comment: @glh, I think there is rather question of `...value = True`

Comment: well I have pretty much nothing. I found the group box like this:     Dim unit As Shape
    Set unit = Worksheets("All").Shapes("UnitType") And I would have to find the selected option button from this 'unit'

Comment: one more question, do you have ActiveX forms or standard sheet forms?

Comment: @KazJaw good popint, not to mention what type of Option Button is used and where? OP can you elaborate.

Comment: @KazJaw standard. Is there a way to for-each through the shapes of a certain group box?

Comment: check this out: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/03/24/select-answers-with-excel-option-buttons/

Comment: @glh I have seen this, and there is nothing on topic.

Comment: you can atleast get your value in a cell, may be put it in a hidden sheet?

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624631/excel-vba-check-if-radio-button-is-selected

Comment: I have it in a cell, but the problem is I would like to get the Alt text of the selected option button. And yes I have also seen that, but I wouldn't want to create a 100 line if-hell.

Comment: Thought I had a solution for you using `shpOptionButton.DrawingObject.GroupBox`.  Looking at this property in a watch window returns the Group Box an Option Button belongs to, but when referenced in code I always get `Nothing` :(  You may be able to find a way to make it work...  (FWIW testing in Excel 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what seems to be a working solution.

(Nod to KazJaw for `Dim ... As OptionButton`.  this seems to be the key to get `.GroupBox` to work)

```
Function WhichOption(shpGroupBox As Shape) As OptionButton
    Dim shp As OptionButton
    Dim shpOptionGB As GroupBox
    Dim gb As GroupBox

    If shpGroupBox.FormControlType <> xlGroupBox Then Exit Function
    Set gb = shpGroupBox.DrawingObject
    For Each shp In shpGroupBox.Parent.OptionButtons
        Set shpOptionGB = shp.GroupBox
        If Not shpOptionGB Is Nothing Then
            If shpOptionGB.Name = gb.Name Then
                If shp.Value = 1 Then
                    Set WhichOption = shp
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Use it like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim shpOpt As OptionButton

    Set shpOpt = WhichOption(Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Group Box 1"))
    Debug.Print shpOpt.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting error Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. On this line: "Debug.Print shpOpt.name"

Comment: that will be because it hasn't found a `On` option button in the group.

Comment: It seems it never enters this if: "If shp.Value = 1 Then"

Comment: Put a break on that line and examine the `Value` of the option button you expect it to return, and change the `If` to test for that value. Also check you are passing the correct GroupBox name (It works for me as is in testing)

Comment: I think my option boxes are members of multiple group boxes or something. When I added counter after "For Each shp In shpGroupBox.Parent.OptionButtons" this line. I was getting weird numbers. UnitType group box got 19 and it has 6 members. An other group box got 7 while it should have had 3.

Comment: What is the meaning of shp? Having trouble understanding, what is happening. Knowing the meaning of your variables might help.

Comment: One of my group boxes was broken which caused this not to work. I re-did the group box contents and now it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I also found out, what broke them. It seems changing the name of the option buttons on the selection and visibility tab breaks it. :/ And I can't figure out how to get Alt text.

Comment: Trying to narrow down the problem. It seems that using special characters like / ( # in the names messes up VBA.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to check OptionButton which are grouped (Grouped in the way we group any type of shape) you could go with this code:

```
Sub Grouped_into_UnitType()
    Dim i!
'grouped into 'UnitType' Shape
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes("UnitType").GroupItems.Count

        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("UnitType").GroupItems(i).ControlFormat
            If .Value = 1 Then
                MsgBox "Chosen item: " & i

            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Edit** having in mind the following picture the code above will solve the problem if we have Option Buttons which are group in the way we group any Shapes placed in the sheet.

The code under the picture will find which option button is selected if they are located within GroupBox. Code check the name of the group in which OptionButton is located.

**Important Note!** the code below didn't work until I switched Excel off and run it again.

[image]

```
Sub Grouped_into_GroupBox_UnitType()

    Dim OB As OptionButton


    For Each OB In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons

    'check if grouped into 'UnitType' Shape
        If OB.GroupBox.Name = "UnitType" Then

            If OB.Value = 1 Then
                MsgBox "Chosen item: " & OB.Name & _
                        vbNewLine & _
                        "Alt text: " & OB.ShapeRange.AlternativeText

            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Grouped Shapes and a Group Box are _not_ the same thing

Comment: Getting this error: Run-time error '1004':
This member can only be accessed for a group.

Comment: I've improved my answer adding additional option which possibly solve your problem. Keep in mind the **note** within answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two standard option buttons:

[image: Options]

To check if its "on" use:

```
Dim opt As Shape
Set opt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Option Button 1")

If opt.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
    Debug.Print "option is ""on"" value of 1"
Else
    Debug.Print "option is ""off"" value of -4146"
End If
```

To get its alternat text use:

```
Debug.Print "Alternate Text is: " & opt.AlternativeText
```

**For a large amount of options** the "FormControlType" property can be used:

```
Dim s as Shape
For Each s In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes

    If s.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then

        If s.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
            Debug.Print "option is ""on"" value of 1"
        Else
            Debug.Print "option is ""off"" value of -4146"
        End If

        Debug.Print "Alternate Text is: " & s.AlternativeText

    End If

Next
```

If you wanted a particular group:

```
Dim s As Shape, o

For Each s In Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes

    If s.FormControlType = xlOptionButton Then

        Set o = s.OLEFormat.Object

        If o.GroupBox.Name = "Group Box 3" Then

            If s.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
                Debug.Print "Option is ""on"" value of 1"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Option is ""off"" value of -4146"
            End If

            Debug.Print "Alternate Text is: " & s.AlternativeText
            Debug.Print "Group: " & o.GroupBox.Name
        End If

        Set o = Nothing
    End If

Next
```

Comment: But like this you would still have to go through every option button, one by one. I could do this, but having if-hell like this wouldn't be nice. If I could get a collection of the option buttons in the group box and for-each through it, that would do it.

Comment: I've added a loop for use on large amounts.

Comment: Problem is, this tests _all_ Option Buttons on the sheet, OP wants to test only those in a particular Group Box

Comment: This would probably work for a single group of option buttons. But this won't allow having multiple groups of option buttons. I will roughly have 10 groups of 10 option buttons each.

Comment: @Firze this was painfull but what you need is to set the OLE object `Set o = s.OLEFormat.Object` and use `o.GroupBox.Name` to get the name

Comment: @Chris this was painfull but what you need is to set the OLE object `Set o = s.OLEFormat.Object` and use `o.GroupBox.Name` to get the name

Comment: Getting error Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set. And yes I did change the name to the UnitType which is my group box's name.

Comment: it seems to be temprimental. it worked for me then it didn't.

Comment: I am completely new to VB, but isn't this: "Dim s As Shape, o" wrong?