# Excel - Returning the caption of the selected option button

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Probably a silly question with a simple answer but I am a real novice when it comes to userforms.

I have "Frame 3" with 5 different option buttons (Dest1, Dest2, Dest3, Dest4, Dest5)  After an option is selected, where is the caption value of the selected option stored?  How can I access that with vba.

Thank you,
Josh

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7624631/2258

Comment: No, the example in the link has no UserForm.

Comment: `Me.Frame3.ActiveControl.Caption`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's just some example code you can use. Add your Option Buttons to groups, and then you can go from there. I used groups since you had multiple frames, and you can check based on group, and have multiple groups, and check which one's selected for each group.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Dim x As Control

     ' Loop through ALL the controls on the UserForm.
     For Each x In Me.Controls
         ' Check to see if "Option" is in the Name of each control.
         If InStr(x.Name, "Option") Then
             ' Check Group name.
             If x.GroupName = "Grp1" Then
                 ' Check the status of the OptionButton.
                 If x.Value = True Then
                     MsgBox x.Caption
                     Exit For
                 End If
             End If
         End If
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I've set the Captions.  I just want the variable name that stores the name of the caption selected by the user.

Comment: I reccomend to use TypeName(x) = "OptionButton" instead of InStr(x.Name, "Option")

Answer (score 3):

You can also access the option buttons through the frame-ojbect that holds them (if you have other frames and controls you don't want to go through):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim oCtrl As Control

    '***** Try only controls in Frame3
    For Each oCtrl In Frame3.Controls
        '***** Try only option buttons
        If TypeName(oCtrl) = "OptionButton" Then
            '***** Which one is checked?
            If oCtrl.Value = True Then
                '***** What's the caption?
                Debug.Print "You have checked option " & oCtrl.Caption
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Label Text associated with an Option Button is obtainable by using `OptionButton1.Caption`

If you are using a loop, just substitute the OptionButton1 with your variable for option buttons and it will pull through the one you need when conditions are met. eg:

```
For xitem = 1 To 5
    xFrm = "OptionButton" & xitem
    For Each fItem In Me.Controls
        If fItem.Name Like xFrm Then
                If fItem.Value Then
                    k = fitem.Caption
                End If
        End If
    Next fItem
Next xitem
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted the caption of the toggle that was selected in an option group to be passed on to a subform filter. e.g. choosing toggle "black" filters subform to all cars where strColour = "black".

I ended up with this:

```
Private Sub OptionGroupName_Click()
    Dim Caption As String
    Caption = OptionGroupName.Controls.Item(OptionGroupName.Value - 1).Caption
    Me.SubformName.Form.Filter = "[SubformField] = """ & Caption & """"
    Me.SubformName.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to dog pile on everyone else's options but I created a function that takes the radio group name and spits out the selected radios coresponding label caption. Was using it in Access not Excel.
Only works provided you name your controls similarly.... 
i.e. (lblRadioButton1 & optRadioButton1)

```
Function GetSelectedRadioButtonCaption(ByVal optionGroupName As OptionGroup) As String
    Dim oCtrl As Control
    Dim oCtrl2 As Control
    Dim optionLabelName As String
    Dim optionLabelObject As Label
    Dim optionButtonObject As OptionButton

    For Each oCtrl In optionGroupName.Controls
        '***** Try only option buttons
        If TypeOf oCtrl Is OptionButton Then
            '***** Which one is checked?
            Set optionButtonObject = oCtrl
            If optionButtonObject.OptionValue = optionGroupName.Value Then
                '***** What's the caption?
                optionLabelName = Replace(oCtrl.Name, "opt", "lbl")
                For Each oCtrl2 In optionGroupName.Controls
                    If oCtrl2.Name = optionLabelName Then
                      Set optionLabelObject = oCtrl2
                      GetSelectedRadioButtonCaption = optionLabelObject.caption
                      Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            If GetSelectedRadioButtonCaption <> "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Exit_GetSelectedRadioButtonCaption:
End Function
```